# Example of weak interactions induced by mixing

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, weak-interaction

I understand that weak interactions are the exchange of W and Z bosons between leptons and quarks (as explained in this other question: [Weak Interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511053/)), but when I read [Light Sterile Neutrinos: A White Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5379) it stated that:

*A sterile neutrino is a neutral lepton with no ordinary weak interaction except those induced by mixing.*

**What other types of interaction are there if not the mixing of particles? Or is this not the meaning of mixing?**
**Could you give me an example of such a mixing interaction?**

Answer (score 2):

> What other types of interaction are there if not the mixing of particles?

If sterile neutrinos do not mix with active (normal) neutrinos, they have only gravity interaction.

> Could you give me an example of such a mixing interaction?

If sterile neutrinos mix with electron neutrinos, there is a very small chance a sterile neutrino produces an electron in a neutrino detector.

Answer (score 0):

Only 90% certain, but I would understand it in the sense of neutrino mixing as in e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0310238.pdf leading to neutrino oscillations. So if the *sterile* neutrino would 'mix' with the other *non-sterile* ones, it still could interact weakly in that way. Because it cannot remain *purely* sterile. But on its own it has no coupling to W/Z.